# Checking which game levels have been completed iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am writing this game with hundreds of levels, but in one of my menus I want to let the user 'quick select' any level by pressing the icon for it (like springboard, except instead of apps, ill have levels). But I also want a little tick to show up in the icon if the level has been completed.

What is the best way of checking which (of my 300+ levels) has been completed, in a totally different file?

NSUserDefaults seems a very clumsy way of doing this. I was thinking more like a loop? But I have no Idea how to do it.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always store `NSArray` object in `NSUserDefaults`. It could be either boolean array indicating whether level completed or not, or just the list of completed levels.

Creating a separate file for it seems like too much hassle to me.

You can find the list of things you can store in `NSUserDefaults` in [its documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

**edit**
Array of booleans could be created like this (since `bool` is a primitive type, we wrap it into `NSNumber`)

```
  NSMutableArray *passedLevels = [NSMutableArray array];
  [passedLevels addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE]];

  if ([[passedLevels objectAtIndex:0] boolValue]) {
      // level passed
  }
```

You can find more methods to manipulate `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` in their documentation.

Comment: OK, how would I go about that?

Comment: @Conor About what? Creating boolean array where each element represents whether level is passed or not? Saving it into defaults object?

Comment: Creating boolean array where each element represents whether level is passed or not